Update grub to safely uninstall Ubuntu dual boot
I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 on partition /dev/nvme0n1p3  (Ubuntu22 from here on), and today I installed Ubuntu 24.04, which I would like to remove, on partition /dev/nvme0n1p4 (Ubuntu24 from here on). The laptop originally came with Windows which I have removed long ago.
The problem is that Ubuntu24 created its own /boot inside the partition that it created, which is different from the original boot partition that I had before. My concern is that if I delete the partition that Ubuntu24 is installed on, my laptop would not boot up.
The BIOS Boot Sequence shows the original boot partition:

That is confirmed with efibootmgr -v which shows:
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,000B,000E,0014,0015,001A,0001
Boot0000* Ubuntu HD(1,GPT,b82bb3f9-8521-4948-9fac-06ca7b6a8d29,0x800,0xfa000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
(irrelevant information removed)

Now HD(1,GPT,b82bb3f9-8521-4948-9fac-06ca7b6a8d29) is the original boot partition /dev/nvme0n1p1 which is mounted on my Ubuntu22 at /boot/efi
$ sudo blkid | grep b82bb3f9-8521-4948-9fac-06ca7b6a8d29
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP" UUID="10EA-56C3" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="b82bb3f9-8521-4948-9fac-06ca7b6a8d29"

$ mount | grep /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)

But when I inspect /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg on the Ubuntu22 I see that it actually points to the Ubuntu24 partition /dev/nvme0n1p4:
$ sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 0f699af1-ac0b-4471-810f-005b4ce4595e root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

$ sudo blkid | grep 0f699af1-ac0b-4471-810f-005b4ce4595e
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="0f699af1-ac0b-4471-810f-005b4ce4595e" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a855d4e4-c4b6-43eb-814a-ca17a03269c4"

The Ubuntu24 partition (/dev/nvme0n1p4) has its own /boot directory which contains the /boot/grub/grub.cfg with the menu that is actually shown on boot.
And now I am worried that if I will delete the Ubuntu24 partition my laptop would not boot up.  How can I safely delete the Ubuntu24 partition?
EDIT: Based on comments, my best path is to set the Ubuntu22 partition as default and then simply delete the Ubuntu24 partition. Many point out that I should run grub-install /dev/sdX to do so but I am not sure which partition in my setup is sdX.
Here is the relevant output of ll /dev/:
ll  /dev | grep nvme
crw-------   1 root 240,   0 Sep 13 07:19 nvme0
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   0 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   1 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1p1
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   5 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1p10
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   6 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1p12
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   2 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1p2
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   3 Sep 12 19:52 nvme0n1p3
brw-rw----   1 root 259,   4 Sep 12 22:14 nvme0n1p4

And the relevant part of lsblk when run in the Ubuntu22 (with my annotation on the left column):
            nvme0n1      259:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
ESP      >  ├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0   500M  0 part /boot/efi
            ├─nvme0n1p2  259:2    0    32G  0 part [SWAP]
Ubuntu22 >  ├─nvme0n1p3  259:3    0 246.5G  0 part /tmp/.X11-unix
            ├─           ... trimmed for brevity ...
            │                                      /
Ubuntu24 >  ├─nvme0n1p4  259:4    0    32G  0 part 
            ├─nvme0n1p10 259:5    0  99.4G  0 part /workspace
            └─nvme0n1p12 259:6    0  66.6G  0 part 

What would be the correct argument to grub-install then?

sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p1 ? pointing to the ESP (EFI System Partition)

sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1p3 ? pointing to the Ubuntu22 partition

sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1   ? pointing to the disk rather than partition



Please do not short form the version info.

The boot GPT UEFI process for ubuntu boot starts with grub @ the UEFI partition. Grub is distributed and at least some is on the target OS drive that installed it. Grub then calls the two main components of initrd... and  vmlinux... in /boot of the target OS. That is true of 22.04 and 24.04. If you want to remove 24.04 then boot into 22.04 and re-install grub (grub-install /dev/sdx) & update-grub. Then you can delete the 24.04 partition and then reboot  22.04 and run update-grub again. (BEWARE: this sort of activity is hazardous so make sure everything is backed up before you start.

@david That's exactly what I want to do but I want to do it safely and hence the question here. Followup questions to your comments are: 1) Should I be able to boot into 22.04 with no issues after deleting the 24.04 partition? 2) I see in many places the advice to run grub-install /dev/sdx but I'm not sure which partition is /dev/sdx in my setup - is it the original grub partition /dev/nvme0n1p1 or the 22.04 partition /dev/nvme0n1p3?

Do not confuse an ESP with /boot. ESP must be FAT32. Most installs have /boot inside / (root). but if separate partition must be Linux format. If you had a working 22.04 and now want it as default all you have to do when booted into it is sudo grub-install That assumes many defaults, but main one is the mount of the ESP - efi system partition which is in fstab. Any examples you see with device like /dev/sdX or /dev/sdXY with NVMe drives will be /dev/nvme0nX and /dev/nvme0nXpY where X is drive & Y is partition. Only a few newer systems have more than one NVMe drive so most are nvme0n1.

@oldfred Yes, you are correct. I did think that ESP and /boot are the same. I edited the question and added more details. So if I understand you correctly then the disk is /dev/nvme0n1, the ESP is /dev/nvme0n1p1, and the 22.04 is installed on /dev/nvme0n1p3 - what do I pass to grub-install?

Your 24.04 install of grub should offer to boot your 22.04 install. If not run sudo update-grub to update grub menu. Once in 22.04 just reinstall grub. And it should add 24.04 to grub menu or do an update to add it to menu. When using two installs you have to manage grub as each install with major updates will make it default. And you have to boot both to get grub updates in menu of other install. If wanting to keep 24.04, better to use custom entries in 40_custom so fewer updates required,

@oldfred Thanks - I am inside the 22.04 - I am just trying to clarify "reinstall grub". What would be the command for that? sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 (the disk)? Or do I need to specify a specific partition?

If you have the correct entry for mounting ESP in your fstab, then you only need sudo grub-install as I posted above. Only if installing to a different drive may you need to specify drive. Installing grub almost never should specify a partition. With UEFI, it knows to use ESP on the specified drive.

Thank you @oldfred!
